# WPF: Is there a "BeforeSelectionChanged" event for the combobox?

Tags: wpf, events, combobox, wpf-controls

Is there a "BeforeSelectionChanged" event for the combobox? I want to verify some stuff before the SelectedItem property changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no PreviewSelectionChanged event. Instead of using two way binding, use one way binding to SelectedItem and get updates through command or SelectionChanged event. That way you can in the handler do some verification and even fake a cancel of the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is, unfortunately.

You might be able to use the `PreviewLeftMouseDown` event and determine if the mouse is over an item in the `ComboBox`. If it is over an item that isn't the `SelectedItem`, you know it is about to change.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, but it sounds like it would be hard to get right.